# Typo3 Single Page content rendering

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to use the t3onepage extension with a slight modification but can't seem to get it to work. That extension only works with a single level backend page structure but I'd like to be able to add subpages as well.

In the backend I want to have a clean and easy to use page structure like this:

```
  Level 1
    Level 2
    Level 2
  Level 1
  Level 1
    Level 2
```

Which is pretty standard. This extension gathers all the content of all these pages and merges them into one single page. I'm just having a problem fetching the Level 2 content.
Here is the extension code that fetches all Level 1 pages, but how to do it for Level 2?

```
20 = CONTENT
20 {
    table = pages
    select.orderBy = sorting

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = CONTENT
        10 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList.field = uid
                orderBy = sorting
                where = colPos = 0
            }

            wrap = <section id="{field:css_id}" class="{field:css_class}">|</section>
            wrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }

    wrap = <main role="main">|</main>
}
```

the generated html code looks something like:

```
<section ids, etc>Level 1</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 1</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 1</section>
```

and I'd like it to have something like:

```
<section ids, etc>Level 1</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 2</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 2</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 1</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 1</section>
<section ids, etc>Level 2</section>
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding contents of the subpages works with this TypoScript. You need to put another CONTENT in first renderObj.

```
lib.onepage {
   20 = CONTENT
   20 {
      table = pages
      select.orderBy = sorting
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
         10 = CONTENT
         10 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
               pidInList.field = uid
               orderBy = sorting
               where = colPos = 0
            }
            wrap = <section id="{field:css_id}" class="{field:css_class}">|</section>
            wrap.insertData = 1
         }
         20 = CONTENT
         20 {
            table = pages
            select {
               orderBy = sorting
               pidInList.field = uid
            }
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
               10 = CONTENT
               10 {
                  table = tt_content
                  select {
                     pidInList.field = uid
                     orderBy = sorting
                     where = colPos = 0
                  }
                  wrap = <section id="{field:css_id}" class="{field:css_class}">|</section>
                  wrap.insertData = 1
               }
           }
           wrap = <main role="main">|</main>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarkusSchwemer Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted. now I'm wrapping the entire renderObj with:
  wrap = <main role="main">|</main>
and it works exactly how I needed it.